# How to show emoji in c# console output?

Tags: c#

I have a problem in output emoji in console.

String starts with Unicode flag "\u" works well, like `"\u263A"`.

However, if just simply copy and paste an emoji into string, like `""`, it does not work.

code test below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string s1 = "";
            string s1_uni = "\ud83c\udf81"; // unicode code for s1
            string s2 = "☺";
            string s2_uni = "\u263A"; // unicode code for s2
            Console.WriteLine(s1);
            Console.WriteLine(s1_uni);
            Console.WriteLine(s2);
            Console.WriteLine(s2_uni);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

`s1` and `s1_uni` can successfully be outputted while `s2` and `s2_uni` failed.

I want to know how to fix this problem.

By the way, the font applied is 'Consolas', which works perfectly in Visual Studio.[image]

Update:

Please note that, I've done some searches in stackoverflow before I present this question. The most common way is to set the Console encoding to `utf-8`, **which is done in the first line of `Main`**.

This way (`Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8`) can not totally fit the situation I presented.

Also, the reason why I make supplement to the console font in the question is to declare that `Consolas` font works perfectly in showing emoji in VS but **failed in console**. **The first emoji failed to show.**

Please do not close this question. Thanks.

Update2:

this emoji can be shown in the VS terminal.

[image]

Update3:

Thank Peter Duniho for help. And you are right.

While we are discussing, I look through the document MS [Unicode Support for the Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-5.0#unicode-support-for-the-console).

> Display of characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (that is, of surrogate pairs) is not supported, even if they are defined in a linked font file.

Code point of the emoji can't be shown in the console is just outside the BMP. And console does not support show code point outside BMP. Therefore, this emoji is not shown.

To change running context which may support this emoji. I did some experiments.

CMD:
[image]

Power Shell:
[image]

Windows Terminal:
[image]

You can see, windows terminal supports it.

Strictly speaking, the problem I met is not a duplicate question in stackoverflow. Because my code just did whatever can be done to meet the requirement. The problem is the running context, not code.

Thank Peter Duniho for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current Windows command line console, `cmd.exe`, still uses GDI+ to render text. And the GDI+ API it uses does not correctly handle combining/surrogate pair characters like the emoji you want to display.

This is true even when using a font that includes the glyph for the character you want, and even when you have correctly set the output encoding for the `Console` class to a Unicode encoding (both of which you've done in your example).

Microsoft appears to be working on improvements to the command prompt code, to upgrade it to use the DirectWrite API instead of GDI+. If and when these improvements are released, the console window should be able to display your emoji correctly. See Github issue [UTF-8 rendering woes #75](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/75)

In the meantime, you can run your program in a context that is able to render these characters correctly, such as Windows Terminal or PowerShell.

Additional details regarding the limitations of the GDI+ font rendering can be found in Github issues [Add emoji support to Windows Console #190](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/190) and [emoji/unicode support mostly broken in windows #2693](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/2693) (the latter isn't about a Windows component per se, but still relates to this problem).