# Does Rider or C# supports all emojis?

Tags: c#, encoding, emoji, rider

I'm building a Console game and i want to print some emojis like:  or ⚔️, but rider doesn´t render them correctly.

These emojis render correctly:

```
string heroName = $"{hero.Name}";
```

while these don't:⚔️☠️

```
string itemName = $"⚔️{item.Name}⚔️"
```

My question is, is there a problem in the way I declare the strings, or is it a Rider configuration problem with the encoding that I need to change?

Comment: Without knowing what "doesn't render them correctly" means and what fonts you have installed/configured for Rider there is no way to answer. (Also how text editors render source code generally should not matter in practice as long as code does what you need).

Comment: [Emoji Sequence](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-sequence/) Emoji Sequences come in many formats, usually invisible to an end-user. Many emojis which appear visually similar are implemented using completely different mechanisms. For instance, ☠️ is `☠` (U+2620,  *Skull And Crossbones*)
and `️` (U+FE0F,  *Variation Selector-16*), see https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%E2%98%A0/ and/or https://emojipedia.org/skull-and-crossbones/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disclaimer:
>
> 1. *I believe, I have some relevant input on your problem.*
>
>    *I'm not a Unicode expert. I don't really understand it well. Just providing my observations based on facts.*
> 2. *You haven't defined what "rendering correctly" and "rendering incorrectly" mean. Therefore, it's a bit hard to provide you a specific answer.*
>
>    *I assume that problem is that emojis are printed in the console as `?` characters.*

Title of your question is:

> Does Rider or C# supports all emojis?

Problem of rendering emojis in Windows Console has nothing to do with Rider or C#.

**Partial solution**

To render Unicode emojis correctly you need to:

1. Set encoding for the output and print emojis:

   ```cs
   Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
   Console.WriteLine("⚔☠"); // Without variations
   Console.WriteLine("⚔️☠️"); // From the original question
   ```
2. Use **Windows Terminal** to run your app:

   [image: Unicode emojis in Windows Terminal]

> The problem of rendering emojis in CMD (without Windows Terminal) has something to do with GDI rendering engine that currently doesn't support font-fallback.

---

**Additional fragmented observations below**:

*It is unclear where did you get your emojis from.*

1. The first emoji that you provided is OK.

   - Copy it:
   - Go to [Full Emoji List, v15.0](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)
   - Press `Ctrl + F`, paste it
   - It's found as [U+1F47E](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f47e) – `Alien monster`
2. The second emoji is different, you can't find it at [Full Emoji List, v15.0](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)

   However, you can find a `Crossed swords` one. It looks exactly like yours on that page:

   [image: Emoji "Crossed swords" from "Full Emoji List, v15.0"]

   **But emoji from that list looks differently in my browser on current StackOverflow page: ⚔**

   It looks like a colored picture on my Windows machine on the "Full Emoji List, v15.0" page just because of the font `Segoe UI Emoji`.

---

If we convert your emojis from the question to bytes, we've got:

- - `f0 9f 91 be` ([link](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-bytes?input=%F0%9F%91%BE))
- ⚔️ - `e2 9a 94 ef b8 8f` ([link](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-bytes?input=%E2%9A%94%EF%B8%8F))
- ☠️ - `e2 98 a0 ef b8 8f` ([link](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-bytes?input=%E2%98%A0%EF%B8%8F))

If you google `ef b8 8f`, you'll find a mysterious `Variation Selector-16` at the [UTF-8 code page (#66)](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/66).

So, if you remove these extra bytes (`ef b8 8f`) of `Variation Selector-16` from `e2 98 a0 ef b8 8f`, you'll end up with bytes `e2 98 a0` which you can encode back to a Unicode character `☠` ([link](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-bytes-to-utf8?base=16&input=e2%2098%20a0)). It looks more simplistic in my browser.

> It has something to do with [Surrogate pairs and variation selectors (Microsoft Learn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/encoding/surrogate-pairs).

---

I believe, these will work in more cases than original ones:

- 
- ⚔
- ☠

In Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10 they looks that way:

[image: Unicode emojis in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10]

But when I run the app, in console they look like this:

[image: Unicode emojis not printed correctly in console]

I'd assume that you refer to such a result as "not rendered correctly".

---

By default, console output encoding is set to `OSEncoding`:

[image: Default value of "Console.OutputEncoding" is "System.Text.OSEncoding"]

So, you need to change it to `Encoding.Unicode`. But it still won't work in CMD.

If you run it in Windows Terminal, it renders text differently, therefore, it will work.

But it will work differently depending on the font being used.

---

Additional references:

- [Windows Command-Line: Inside the Windows Console](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-inside-the-windows-console/)
- [Unicode in Windows CMD](https://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html)
- StackOverflow [answer from Peter Duniho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67510140/3503521) for "How to show emoji in c# console output?"
- [Everything You Need To Know About Emoji](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/11/character-sets-encoding-emoji)